# Is this way of using std::string safe?

Tags: c++, string, stl

I am writing a string class (Utf8String) that wraps (has) a std::string (because it's handy).

For some reason I have to access the internal buffer of the wrapped std::string to write directly into it. I know this is dirty and against encapsulation principles and all that, but I have to do it.

Let the following Utf8String class members :

```
std::basic_string< char > m_sBuf;

inline char * Reserve( uint32_t nNewByteCap )
{
   m_sBuf.reserve( nNewByteCap );
   return const_cast< char * >( m_sBuf.c_str() );
}

inline void Resize( uint32_t nNewByteCount )
{
   // Some stuff ...
   m_sBuf.resize( nNewByteCount, ' ' );
}
```

In order to do something like this :

```
Utf8String sMessage;
char * sBuffer = sMessage.Reserve( 1024 );
uint32_t nRealLen = some_c_function_write_to_buffer( sBuffer, sMessage.Capacity() );
sMessage.Resize( nRealLen );
```

I am not certain how the STL works internally. As far as i know, it accepts having null characters lost in the middle of a std::string, so placing a null character before the actual end of the string should not be a problem.

Since STL implementations can be different on different platforms, testing on mine won't mean that it works on other platforms too.

Do you see something in this piece of code that can break the std::string object i'm using ? Thanks for your help.

PS : I can't use C++11.

Comment: Nothing about your use of `reserve` and `resize` is legitimate. Writing beyond the *size* of the string has undefined behaviour, no matter the capacity.

Comment: Are you claiming `return m_sBuf.c_str();` in a function returning `char *` even *compiles* ?

Comment: @KerrekSB I know this is not the right way of using the std::string, this is why i'm asking as i doubt there will be problems. What if i'm using resize instead of reserve ?

WhozCraig i wrote this code for the question, i just forgot the const_cast<>, but that's not really the point.

Answer (score 2):

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str:

> Writing to the character array accessed through c_str() is undefined behavior.
>   You shouldn't do that.

Safer code:

```
Utf8String sMessage;
std::array<char, 1024> buffer;
uint32_t nRealLen = some_c_function_write_to_buffer( buffer.data(), buffer.size() );
sMessage.Assign(sBuffer.begin(), sBuffer.end());
```

The last line assumes you have in your string class:

```
template<typename InIt>
void Assign(InIt begin, InIt end) {
    m_sBuf.assign(begin, end);
}
```

(or equivalent).

This is better because it doesn't use access to the data returned by c_str and it doesn't attempt to manage the memory in std::string manually.

Comment: It would be even better of the resulting `sMessage` wasn't built from all 1024 chars of `buffer` when only `nRealLen` number of them are required.

Comment: Probably. I left that code as it was in the OP's question and focused on string abuse in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought about doing something like that, by creating a char buffer using new, and assign this buffer to the string (for example), but my boss does not like it, he wants something similar to the CString::GetBuffer(), CString::Release() from the MFC, that's why i came up with the design in the question. Besides std::array is C++, which i can't use.

Comment: @Virus721 Whether he "likes it" or not doesn't make it anymore right. Invoking undefined behavior is a recipe for disaster, and I only pray whatever you build and he manages isn't mission critical. Do it right. If needed refactor your code and manage a `std::vector<char>` appropriately.

Comment: No hopyfully this software isn't going into a plane ! :) I'm probably going to use a vector after all. I thought using std::string wouls spare me to take care of the terminating zero.

Comment: In particular, the `CString::GetBuffer` and `CString::Release` model is bad - very very bad: it is an interface that relies on client code to be written correctly (just DON'T!), and asks you to understand the underlying implementation (no no no!). When you do not use these two APIs correctly, the application is silently corrupted.

Comment: I don't like it either !